# Api-Platform: using PUT for creating resources

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I would like to use the PUT method for creating resources. They are identified by an UUID, and since it is possible to create UUIDs on the client side, I would like to enable the following behaviour:

- on PUT /api/myresource/4dc6efae-1edd-4f46-b2fe-f00c968fd881 if this resource exists, update it
- on PUT /api/myresource/4dc6efae-1edd-4f46-b2fe-f00c968fd881 if this resource does not exist, create it

It's possible to achieve this by implementing an `ItemDataProviderInterface` / `RestrictedDataProviderInterface`.

However, my resource is actually a subresource, so let's say I want to create a new `Book` which references an existing `Author`.

My constructor looks like this:

```
/**
 * Book constructor
 */
public function __construct(Author $author, string $uuid) {
    $this->author = $author;
    $this->id = $uuid;
}
```

But I don't know how to access the `Author` entity (provided in the request body) from my `BookItemProvider`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I may be way off here, I do not know about neither api-platform.com nor the `ItemDataProviderInterface`. But if I understand it correctly, `Author` has a one to many relationship with `Book`? In that case, perhaps in the `AuthorType` should have books as a `CollectionType` and include `'allow_add'' => true`.

Comment: After quickly checking out the api-platform.com, which looks awesome, I believe that my above answer is complete rubbish. Please ignore it.

Comment: I think you need to look into [Api-Platform event system](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events#the-event-system) and do customization of PUT requests using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In API Platform many things that should occur on item creation is based on the kind of request it is. It would be complicated to change.

Here are 2 possibilities to make what you want.

First, you may consider to do a custom route and use your own logic. If you do it you will probably be happy to know that using the option `_api_resource_class` on your custom route will enable some listeners of APIPlaform and avoid you some work.

The second solution, if you need global behavior for example, is to override API Platform. Your main problem for this is the `ReadListener` of ApiPlatform that will throw an exception if it can't found your resource. This code may not work but here is the idea of how to override this behavior:

```
class CustomReadListener
{
    private $decoratedListener;

    public function __construct($decoratedListener)
    {
        $this->decoratedListener = $decoratedListener;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        try {
            $this->decoratedListener->onKernelRequest($event);
        } catch (NotFoundHttpException $e) {
            // Don't forget to throw the exception if the http method isn't PUT 
            // else you're gonna break the 404 errors
            $request = $event->getRequest();

            if (Request::METHOD_PUT !== $request->getMethod()) {
                throw $e;
            }

            // 2 solutions here:

            // 1st is doing nothing except add the id inside request data
            // so the deserializer listener will be able to build your object


            // 2nd is to build the object, here is a possible implementation

            // The resource class is stored in this property
            $resourceClass = $request->attributes->get('_api_resource_class');

            // You may want to use a factory? Do your magic.
            $request->attributes->set('data', new $resourceClass());
        }
    }
}
```

And you need to specify a configuration to declare your class as service decorator:

```
services:
    CustomReadListener:
        decorate: api_platform.listener.request.read
        arguments:
            - "@CustomReadListener.inner"
```

Hope it helps. :)

More information:

- Information about event dispatcher and kernel events: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html
- ApiPlatform custom operation: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers
- Symfony service decoration: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Comment: Hey Nek, your solution sounds great! I'm just struggling with service decoration (never used that before). I've got a "The service "AppBundle\EventListener\ReadListener" has a dependency on a non-existent service api_platform.listener.request.read.inner exception (Symfony 4.0.6 w/ flex + api-pack). The argument must have an @ ("@api_platform.listener.request.read.inner"), otherwise it's a string passed to the constructor.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like the `decoration_inner_name` param is mandatory. Unclear in the doc. I'm going on.

Comment: Sorry, my service definition was wrong. I edited it should be ok right now. Do not hesitate to refer to the Symfony documentation I linked on my post.

Comment: Hi Nek, thanks for your help, I eventually managed to achieve what I wanted. Hard to do this with subresources (can not auto-hydrate the Author entity from request), but I finally bypass this.