# Is there a way to handle duplicate enteries?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I am using the api-platform framework with a MySQL backend. I am getting errors when API clients use the POST end point to submit data if there is already an entry in the database.

Currently I am using a PRE_WRITE EventSubscriberInterface class to find the original database entry and delete it. However this seems incredable inefficient compared to a simple update action.

I am able to update the existing database entry, but then I'm unable to remove/stop the POST'd an item from being executed.

Is there a way around this? Ether to change the INSERT action to an ...ON DUPLICATE... or to simple stop the data the user post'd from being saved to the database?

Comment: _"Ether to change the INSERT action to an ...ON DUPLICATE."_ - If you have an idea how you might be able to solve it, please test it before asking. So is for when you're completely stuck and you've tried all other options.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you basically want either an INSERT, if it's a new dataset or an UPDATE, if the dataset already exists? If so, this question sounds like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767594/api-platform-using-put-for-creating-resources#49770818

Comment: I know how I would like to solve it, but I haven't found a way of altering the SQL statment before its carried out. I would also prefer a database agnostic method which didnt rely on the end user running MySQL

Comment: Either alter the statement to ignore the duplicate, or handle the duplicate error. There's really no alternative to those two options. Each database has its own form of duplicate handling, so you'll need a database specific method unless you have a driver that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the property "UniqueEntity" to set what's make your entity unique.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity("slug")
 */
class Article
{
   //...


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;
}
```